# How to change logged-in user permission in hook_node_view?

Tags: nodes, rules, users

Can anyone please let me know how can we achieve the following scenario

I want to change the role of the logged-in user before viewing the node. When you click on the node for viewing it, I want the roles to be changed and then display the content accordingly with the access permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Rules module

Consider using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. The actual details of your question need some further refinement (to better explain what you actually want to achieve, and to include some of your extra comments), but here is a draft version of the rule to do what you are lookiung for:

- **Event** : Content is viewed (located within "Node")
- **Condition** : logged in user = userid associated with the node
- **Action** : Grant role to user

However, since this event only seems to happen "after" the content is viewed, you probably encounter some access denied situation (refer to [open issue 1336402](https://www.drupal.org/node/1336402) for more details). I haven't been able to find some event like "when a user encounters an access denied" (need to do more research if that's doable). Therefor consider the alternative described below also.

## Use Content Access module integration with the Rules module

Another approach might be to use the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module, and the Content Access Rules Integrations module. So that "After saving content" (= Event), you "Give 'authenticated user' the permission to 'view own content' for the specific node" (= Action). That way, the permission is set when the node is edited already (which is not exacty what you are asking for in your question, but would achieve the same result) I believe.

This would be a variation of what is explained in [this article](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/content-access/) also (within "Access Control Customized for Your Needs").

## Use Rabbit Hole module

In one of your comments you wrote "*I wanted to compare the logged in user is same as the one associated with the node ... if they are same then allow the access else deny access to the node*". Even though I've no experience with it, it appears to me that possibly the [Rabbit Hole](https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module might be a solution for you. Here is part of what it says on its project page:

> ... Perhaps you want a user to be able to view nodes that he has created, but no one else's.

Comment: Yes. I need exactly what you have written. But there is no event called "Before viewing the node", is it?

Comment: I enhance my answer (exact event to be used), and added the Content Access alternative to consider. Does this help somehow?

Comment: If I use "content is viewed" event, actions are not executed after opening the node details page but are executed only if you refresh the opened node details page. Content Access module I shall try.

Comment: These modules cannot resolve my problem. Is there any way I can do it in the code itself? I have created a view for nodes and i'm opening the node from there. So can I add something to the code in view/modules/node/ files and achieve this?

Comment: Just discovered a possible alternative for the "Content is viewed" event (to be used in Rules): You may want to try using even "System > Drupal is initializing". Curious to hear if that gets it to work ...

Answer (score 2):

using  [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7),here you can check user role by using

```
global $user;
$roles=$user->roles;
```

Comment: I wanted to compare the logged in user is same as the one associated with the node (my understanding on associated with the node means the creator of the node) if they are same then allow the access else deny access to the node.

Comment: Is my understanding correct? The following code is not working as expected. Can anyone please correct me if i'm wrong.

if ($op == 'view') {         
      if (user_access('view any ' . $type . ' content', $account) || (user_access('view own ' . $type . ' content', $account))
        {
                global $user;
                if ($user->uid == $node->uid) {
                return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
                }
                else
                {
                return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
                }        
        }

  }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below modules :

1. [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)

> Nodeaccess is a Drupal access control module which provides view, edit
>   and delete access to nodes. Users with the 'grant node permissions'
>   permission will have a grant tab on node pages which allows them to
>   grant access to that node by user or role. Administrators can set
>   default access controls per content type, and also define which roles
>   are available to grant permissions to on the node grants tab.

2. [Userpoints Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_nodeaccess)

> The Drupal userpoints nodeaccess module enables you to sell access to
>   a single node for a specific category and amount of userpoints.